# can't submit app to app store with error: "non-public selector"

Tags: ios

I have problem: can't submit app to the App Store.I build an archive of the app in Xcode 5, validate the archive for the App Store and have error: **"the app references non-public selectors in Payload/MyProj.app/MyProj:startIndex"**. 
In app used Googleplus SDK (latest version). When i delete this SDK from app, validation was successful. I find similar problem:https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=677. 
Can any help?

Answer (score 2):

Same Issued I found when submitted App to Apple with [Google Analytics SDK](http://www.google.com/analytics/) as no sloution. But it just gave me the Warning like `Non-public selectors` and after the 3-4 days of stress means Review the app got approved and it now on app store. As you too describe these perfect steps and worked fine for me too.

- Use google-plus-ios-sdk 1.3.0 in an iOS app
- Build an archive of the app in Xcode 5
- Validate the archive for the App Store
- Xcode 5 complains that "startIndex" is in Apple's private API.

[image]